# Firing an event to the parent page when a user control finishes loading in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with an ASP.NET project that was created by a team elsewhere in the company. One of the pages that I am working with features a userControl that queries the database to populate a generic field. The information from this query is then used by the parent page (that is, the page that contains the userControl) to set the selectedIndex of a dropdown.

The issue that I am having is that the parent page loads before the userControl, which means that the parent page loads before the results of the query are available. As a result, the selectedIndex of the dropdown is only ever set to a default index.

Based on jrista's answer to [ASP .NET: when UserControls loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949517/asp-net-when-usercontrols-loads) , I understand that the page.OnLoad event fires before the userControl.OnLoad event. I also understand that there is no OnLoadComplete event for user controls, which I was hoping I could use to make an event that fires on the parent page when the user control finishes loading.

I've heard that the Pre-Render event can be used to the same effect ([based on this question over on the asp forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1658733.aspx?OnLoadComplete+and+UserControls)), but is this the only approach? Is there a better way to fire an event from a userControl to the parent page when the user control finishes loading? Or is this simply not a good practice and would I be better to somehow change the code to avoid this situation?

Comment: Page PreRender should be fine, which is after Control Load. I remember PreRender as the last step where you can populate data before displaying it to the user. If you want later updates than PreRender you can fallback to using ajax after the pages has been presented to the user (but shouldn't be needed in this case)

Comment: Yes, I had considered using Ajax, but I think PreRender is a much more elegant solution in this case. If I hadn't already implemented Nathan's solution, I think I would go with PreRender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating an interface that your page will implement like so:

```
 public interface INotifyChildLoaded
 {
     void OnUserControlLoaded(Control control);
 }
```

Then, implement that interface on your page

```
 public class MyPage : Page, INotifyChildLoaded
 { 
     public void OnUserControlLoaded(Control control) { ... }
     ....
 }
```

Finally, during your user control load event, call the method:

```
 public void MyControl_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
     ....
     (Page as INotifyChildLoaded).OnUserControlLoaded(this);
 }
```